# Find Nearest Value based upon datetime in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

We have a sensor, which records 'x' when told by another sensor. What this mean is, the observation is made at random time and random frequency within a hour. Here is how data looks like

```
> df
date         time        x
1/1/2018     00:24:12    10
1/1/2018     00:47:17    14
1/1/2018     1:17:11     12
1/1/2018     1:34:34     17
1/1/2018     1:52:23     15
1/1/2018     2:10:59     12
```

and so on till 31/1/2018. To compare it to another dataset, I want to find value recorded at time nearest to hour mark. Ex:

```
date         time     x
1/1/2018      00      10
1/1/2018      01      14 (Since 00:47:17 is -13 minutes to 01 as compared to 1:17:11 which is + 17 minutes)
1/1/2018      02      15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `DatetimeIndex` first, then [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) with [`Timestamp.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.floor.html) and last [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with `method='nearest'`:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + ' ' + df['time'])
rng = pd.date_range(df.index.min().floor('H'), df.index.max().floor('H'), freq='H')

df = df.reindex(rng, method='nearest')
print (df)
                         date      time   x
2018-01-01 00:00:00  1/1/2018  00:24:12  10
2018-01-01 01:00:00  1/1/2018  00:47:17  14
2018-01-01 02:00:00  1/1/2018   1:52:23  15
```

Last if necessary remove `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df = df.reindex(rng, method='nearest').reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
       date      time   x
0  1/1/2018  00:24:12  10
1  1/1/2018  00:47:17  14
2  1/1/2018   1:52:23  15
```